# Prototype chain can't get Object()?

Tags: javascript, prototype-oriented

I read an [article](http://www.packtpub.com/article/using-prototype-property-in-javascript) which explains what prototype chain is.

It says that if I try to access an object's property but it doesn't have it, javascript engine will try it's `.constructor.propotype`. If it doesn't have it either then try `.construtor.propotype.constructor.propotype`. Untill it find the built-in Object().

But I test this:

```
function a() {}
b = new a();
```

then:

```
c = b.constructor.prototype
```

I get an empty `a` object.

then:

```
d = c.constructor.prototype
```

I get an empty `a` object.

It loops. No matter how many `.constructor.prototype` I call, it can't find Object(). What's wrong? Do I misunderstand the prototype chain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JS OOP the `constructor` and `prototype` properties are flaky, in that they aren't set for you when you perform inheritance. You are supposed to manually set/alter them to implement inheritance. See, for example, [this tutorial](http://phrogz.net/js/classes/OOPinJS2.html).

It looks like the way you're trying to climb the prototype chain (by traversing through `.constructor.prototype`) never really reaches the `Object` top-level prototype, since when you have `function a(){}` the right `constructor` and `prototype` properties aren't set on a. I can't even manage to coerce them onto `a`; in Chrome I get:

```
> function a(){}
undefined
> a.constructor.prototype
function Empty() {}
> a.constructor.prototype = Object.prototype
Object
> a.constructor.prototype
function Empty() {} // hmmmm, the assignment didn't take...
```

Of course the runtime doesn't need to do this, since it has a reference to the actual prototype of each object. I.e. the language doesn't do the lookup via `.constructor.prototype`, it saves the prototype *of each instance* internally. So you can see how the lookup chain works if instead of `.constructor.prototype` you use `.__proto__`:

```
function a(){}
b = new a();
b.__proto__ === Object.prototype; // false
b.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype; // true since we reached the top of the prototype chain
```

It is important to note that the property `__proto__` has never been standard and in ES5 was standardised in a slightly different manner:

```
obj.__proto__ === Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
```

This renders `.__proto__` deprecated.

Comment: Though I have understood, the answer is more detailed so that I should accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that I asked a stupid question.

if A is a function:

A.prototype.constructor === A

if A isn't a function:

A.prototype in a normal property.

So (in standard) there is no way to climb up the prototype chain.